# Scheduler Design? Multiple Events on the same timeline starting at different times

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

I have multiple objects (Object1, Object2 and Object3) which MAY want to utilize a callback. If it is decided that an object wants to be registed
for a periodic callback, they all will use a 30 second reset rate. The object will choose when it registers for a callback (that it would want
at that fixed interval of 30 seconds going forward).

If I wanted to give each object its own internal Timer (such as a timer on a seperate thread) this would be a simple
problem. However each timer would need to be on a seperate thread, which would grow too much as my object count grows.

So for example:

at T=10 seconds into runtime, Object 1 registers for a callback. Since the callback occurs every 30 seconds, its next fire event will
be at T=40, then T=70, T=100 etc.

say 5 seconds later (T=15), Object 2 registers for a callback. Meaning its next call is at T=45, T=75, T=105 etc.

Lastly 1 second after Object 2, Object 3 registers for a callback. Its callback should be invoked at T=46 etc.

A dirty solution I would have for this to for everything to calculate its delta from the first registered Object.
So Object 0 is 0, Object 1 is 10 and Object 3 is 11. Then in a constantly running loop, once the 30 seconds have elapsed, I know
that Object 0's callback can process, and within 10 seconds from that point I can then call object 1's callback etc.
I don't like that in a way that stay busy waits as a while loop must constantly be running. I guess SystemSleep calls may not be as different using semaphores.

Another thought I had was finding the lowest common multiple between the fire events. For example if I kew it was possible every 3 seconds I may have to fire an event, i would keep track of that.

I think essentially what I am trying to make is some sort of simple scheduler? I'm sure I am hardly the first person to do this.
I am trying to come up with a performant solution. a While Loop or a ton of timers on their own threads would make this easy, but that is not a good solution.

Any ideas? Is there a name for this design?

Comment: Possibly Boost ASIO, or RxCpp could be useful frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a priority queue, a heap or similar to manage your timed callbacks using a single timer. You check what callback needs to be called next and that is the time you set for the timer to wake you up.

But if all callbacks use a constant 30s repeat then you can just use a queue. New callbacks are added to the end as a pair of callback and (absolute) timestamp and the next callback to call will always be at the front. Every time you call a callback you add it back to the queue with a timestamp 30s increased.

Comment: That makes sense! Yeah each callback will be at a constant time. The only thing that varies is when it is called

Comment: I guess the only thing is figuring out how to manipulate what actually executes the queue? the rest of that queue concept makes sense but wouldn't i need to adjust timing of that

Comment: Either `alarm()`, `setitimer()`, `sleep()` or `select/poll/epoll()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking about the case where I have multiple intervals and the only thing I can't get behind is how I interupt sleeps

Comment: @jdoe Why would you interrupt sleeps? The sleep would be timed to the next time you need to wake up. There is nothing that would require waking up early.